# How can I make passportjs google login oauth work with JWT instead of creating session through serialize/deserialize method?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

The below code will works perfectly If I add the serialize/deserialize passportjs method, which creates a session. I am working to create Json Web  Token, not session. Any tutorial, suggestion or clear sample would be greatly appreciated.I use nodejs.

I understood the pro/con and basic overview of how JWT works. I learned it from the following source.

1. https://medium.com/@rahulgolwalkar/pros-and-cons-in-using-jwt-json-web-tokens-196ac6d41fb4
2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication
3. https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token
4. https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide

/

**No JWT code**

```
var express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mysql = require("mysql"),
    connection = require("express-myconnection"),
    morgan = require("morgan"),
    app = express(),

    passport = require("passport"),
    GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy;


app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/main.html");
});


// #1
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: "32434m",
            clientSecret: "23434",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                console.log("profile.id: " + profile.id);
                return done(null, profile.id); // that is being serealized(added in session)
            });
        }
    )
);

// #1
app.get("/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate(
        "google", {
            scope: ["profile", "email"]
        }));

// #2
app.get("/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: "/google_callback_fail",
        successRedirect: "/google_callback_success"
    })
);

app.get("/google_callback_success", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.send("google_callback_success \n");
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log("isLoggedIn req.user: " + req.user);

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("isAuthenticated TRUE");
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/notloggedin");
}

app.get("/notloggedin", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.user: " + req.user);
    res.json("not loggedin");
});

app.get("/google_callback_fail", function(req, res) {
    res.json("the callback after google DID NOT authenticate the user");
});


app.listen(3000);
```

**JWT code attempt. The problem is I need to add serialize/deserialize, which I don't want to, since, I don't want to use session. I want JWT**

```
var express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mysql = require("mysql"),
    connection = require("express-myconnection"),
    morgan = require("morgan"),
    app = express(),

    passport = require("passport"),
    GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy,

    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    passportJWT = require("passport-jwt"),
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt,
    JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;


var jwtOptions = {};
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
jwtOptions.secretOrKey = 'secret';



app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/main.html");
});


// #1
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: "s-s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            clientSecret: "23redsf",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function() {

                console.log("\nprofile.id: " + profile.id);

                return done(null, profile.id); // that is being serealized(added in session)
            });
        }
    )
);

// #1
app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate(
        "google", {
            scope: ["profile", "email"]
        }
    )
);

// #2
app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: "/google_callback_fail",
        successRedirect: "/google_callback_success"
    })
);

app.get("/google_callback_success", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var payload = { id: user.id };
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
    var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {
        console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);
        console.log('jwt_payload.id: ' + jwt_payload.id);
    });
    passport.use(strategy);
    res.send("google_callback_success \n" + 'token: ' + token);
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log("isLoggedIn req.user: " + req.user);

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("isAuthenticated TRUE");
        var payload = { id: user.id };
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
        console.log('token: ' + token);
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/notloggedin");
}

app.get("/notloggedin", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.user: " + req.user);
    res.json("not loggedin");
});

app.get("/google_callback_fail", function(req, res) {
    res.json("the callback after google DID NOT authenticate the user");
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    console.log("logged out");
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/logout");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The code `return done(null, profile.id); // that is being serialized(added in session)` is the problem. What should I replace it so that I don't have to use sessions? I want to replace it with JWT.

Comment: Is there no way to create JWT with passportjs?

Comment: can someone please refer me good jsonwebtoken nodejs examples?

Answer (score 14):

https://www.sitepoint.com/spa-social-login-google-facebook/

basically after google authentication is done, you create a jwt for the user.

```
// src/index.js
function generateUserToken(req, res) {
  const accessToken = token.generateAccessToken(req.user.id);
  res.render('authenticated.html', {
    token: accessToken
  });
}

app.get('/api/authentication/google/start',
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: 
  ['openid', 'profile', 'email'] }
));
app.get('/api/authentication/google/redirect',
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }),
  generateUserToken
);
```

Comment: After that i still get `Failed to serialize user into session
`

Comment: @ValRob Have you included `{ session: false }` on the `passport.authenticate` second parameter?

Answer (score 8):

After a long time spent trying to find a workaround, I finally came across this. The best option thus far, works perfectly for me.

```js
app.get('/auth/google/callback',  
  passport.authenticate('google', 

  { failureRedirect: '/', session: false }), (req, res) => {

    const jwt = createJWTFromUserData(req.user);
    const htmlWithEmbeddedJWT = `
    <html>
      <script>
        // Save JWT to localStorage
        window.localStorage.setItem('JWT', '${jwt}');
        // Redirect browser to root of application
        window.location.href = '/';
      </script>
    </html>
    `;

    res.send(htmlWithEmbeddedJWT);
});
```

Comment: How do you do this when you have front end and back end running on two different ports? (Say, front end on :3000 and node on :5000)

Comment: @davyCode False. The front end and back end are not on the same port.

Comment: is localStorage suitable for auth token?

Comment: @HossamMaher yes you can store auth token in localStorage

Comment: @davyCode what if you have an API working as a web service so not always request will be coming from a website.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by opening the google auth screen in a new window and writing the JWT back using `window.postMessage()`.

App:

```
const Login = () => {
    const setToken = function(e) {
    if (
      e.origin === origin &&
      e.data &&
      e.data.command === 'token-ready' &&
      e.data.info &&
      e.data.info.token
    ) {
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', e.data.info.token);

      e.source.postMessage(
        {
          command: 'info',
          info: {
            complete: true,
          },
        },
        e.origin
      );
    }
  };

  
  window.addEventListener('message', setToken, false);

  const login = () => {
    window.open(loginUri);
  };

  return (<button onClick={login}>Login</button>
}
```

Server Response:

```
const html = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Authenticated</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      Authenticated successfully.
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
          console.dir(e)
          if (e.origin === "${postBackUri}" && e.data && e.data.info && e.data.info.complete) {
              window.close();
          }
        }, false);
      
        opener.postMessage({
          command: "token-ready",
          info: {
            token: "${token}",
          },
        }, "${postBackUri}");
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
`;

return res.send(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
app.get('/google',passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

// callback google 
app.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, failureRedirect: '/login/failed' }),
  (req, res) => {
    // generate new access token
    const acc = GenerateAccessToken(req.user);
    res.cookie('au_ac',acc,{httpOnly:true});
    return res.redirect(CLIENT_URL)
  }
);
```

And here to verify the token

```
app.get('/is/authenticated', async(req, res) => {
  const { au_ac } = req.cookies;
  if (!au_ac) return res.json({ authenticated: false });

  try {
    const user = await Verify_Access_Token(au_ac);
    return res.json({ user, authenticated: true })
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(401).json({ authenticated: false })
  }
});
```

This's a simple example your app should have **Refresh Token** also.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Passport-JWT](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/). As they say, this module lets you authenticate endpoints using a JSON web token. It is intended to be used to secure RESTful endpoints without sessions.

Comment: The main problem is it is not handleable using http clients (not browser) because of popup and redirections. It seems no way except the one @davyCode said, or set a server side cookie. Actually passport must have create auth link but it have not.